# SUM based on list of categories

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

Consider the following Excel

```
    A      B    C    D
1   foo    7         whaa
2   bar    5    AA
3   baz    9    BB
4   bal    1    AA
5   oof    3         blah
6   aba    9    C
```

Extra:

- Each row has either a value in column `C` OR in column `D`
- The values in column `C`are categories (in this example ÀA`,`BB`,`C`)
- The values in column `D`can be anything

I need a `SUM` (based on column `A`) as follows:

- `SUM` of column `B` for all lines that have a value in (any value) in column `D` (called `Rest`)
- `SUM` of column `B` for each category in column `C`. I have a list of the categories (see below)

So like this:

```
   A      B
1  Rest   10     <----- 7 + 3
2  AA     6      <----- 5 + 1
3  BB     9
4  C      9
```

What formulas do I need in column `B` above to get this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or, you can use sumproduct to solve:

```
H2=SUMPRODUCT(($D$4:$D$9=IF(G2="Rest","",G2))*$C$4:$C$9)

H2=SUMIF($D$4:$D$9,IF(G2="Rest","",G2),$C$4:$C$9)
```

[image]